# Question about general torus knot lengths

Tags: knot-theory

Can anyone send me a reference about calculating the length of a thin string wound on a p,q torus with major radius R and minor radius r in terms of p, q, R and r? This may appear trivial but I have found nothing on extensive Google search as most interest seems to be in ideal (thick) string knots on tori.

Comment: Isn't this a vector calculus question; not a question in knot theory?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by your major and minor radius?  Parts of your question sound like a physical knot theory question, but other parts sound rather different.  I suspect like Anthony that this may not be a knot theory question, perhaps more of a differential geometry question for a very specific embedding of the torus knot in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you seek, I think, but if you select a particular curve
parameterization, it is not difficult to compute the length.
For example, with this parameterization,
$$x(t) = (\cos (p t)+3) \cos (q t)$$
$$y(t) = (\cos (p t)+3) \sin (q t)$$
$$z(t) = \sin (p t)$$
here is the knot for $(p,q)=(20,3)$:

---

[image: TorusKnot]

---

Then evaluate
$$
L = \int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{ \dot x^2 + \dot y^2 + \dot z^2 } \; dt
$$
where $\dot x = dx/dt$.
For $(p,q)=(20,3)$, I get $L \approx 138.34$.